# Android: Monitoring for Calendar notifications with the 4.x calendar API

Tags: android, android-calendar

I'm wanting to monitor for calendar reminders with the android 4.0 upwards calendar API. Basically I want to get an event when a notification pops up in the notification bar and also to be notified when it either gets dismissed or a "snooze" is chosen.

Is there a content observer that allows for this?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible.

A content observer (in essence) is for getting notifications when the data for a cursor changes.

You can't find out when the Calendar sends out a notification. Posting a notification is an event that's "private" between the app that posts the notification and the system. When users dismiss a notification, the system sends out an Intent. Theoretically you can filter for that Intent, but if that functionality isn't documented by the app, then you can't count on it working "forever", so you shouldn't use it.

The same applies to "snooze".

Is there a reason you want to trap this?

Comment: I'm guessing that there must be a database change taking place when a notification comes up and when it's dismissed. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CalendarContract.CalendarAlertsColumns.html seems the most likely area. I'm wanting to trap this information so that my notification manager app can pick up on the event. I used to use the accessibility service, but in android 4.2 the notification keeps triggering while in snooze mode before the event comes up.